# How can I use 3D SUMIF function over a single worksheet?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a XL Doc with 2 worksheets. In one worksheet (Scope) I have all the resources listed down with their allocation and capacity. In the second worksheet (Summary)I will be including tickets to the resources that I mentioned in my first worksheet and the hours for each ticket will also be inserted.

[image]

1st Worksheet Name - `Summary`

2nd Worksheet Name - `Scope`

There are 3 columns in `Scope` sheet namely, `Resource` , `Ticket` and `Hours`.
In `Summary` Sheet I have `Resource` and `Allocation` columns.

I need to get the total hours for a resource in `Summary` sheet and display it on `Allocation` column.
Note: A resource will have multiple tickets allocated.

I tried below formula in `Summary` sheet. But it shows value 0, even I inserted hours in `Scope` sheet.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&Scope&"'!"&"A2:A500"),C4,INDIRECT("'"&Scope&"'!"&"I2:P500")))
```

C4 cell contains the name of the resource.

Please help me to sort this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2SWB.png)

Comment: Why do you use `Indirect`? You can just use `SUMIF(Scope!A2:A500)` directly.

Comment: This will return the values in the same worksheet as it select the range in the same worksheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(Scope!A2:A500, C4, INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2, COLUMN(I:P), 4, 1, "Scope")&":"&ADDRESS(500, COLUMN(I:P), 4, 1))))
```

Comment: Hi Jeeped,

I tried your formula but then it select the range in the same worksheet. It doesn't get the values from the Scope worksheet. I have added the picture of the worksheet and I need to insert this formula in Allocation (SP) Column.


Thanks in advance